# Avoiding 404 errors when enabling Pagespeed on Google Appengine (java)

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, pagespeed

I recently enabled Google PageSpeed on AppEngine for a website with a java backend.  However, in my server logs, I keep finding "No handlers matched this URL" errors for paths like the following:

```
 /x/s.[APP-ID].appspot.com/[HOST-NAME]/path/to/image-with-modified-name.png
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem?  Is it a configuration issue or a problem with my code, or is it just an AppEngine bug?  I haven't been able to find anything by googling.  Thanks!

Comment: Were you ever able to address this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: No - it is still happening.  I'm not sure if it's a Google bug or if I ought to change something.  It doesn't seem to impact performance, though.